# How Java linker works?

Tags: java, linker, jvm, specifications

I want to know how Java linker works. Specifically, in which order it combines classes, interfaces, packages, methods and etc into jvm-executable format. I have found some information [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#71418), but there is not so much information about linking order.

Comment: What do mean by order? From the first sentence on that page: "The Java virtual machine **dynamically** loads , links, and initializes classes and interfaces." By inference, this is done on-demand in most JVMs.

Comment: More to the point, what do you mean by *'linker'?* There isn't any such thing in Java.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Java "linker".  There is, however, the concept of a classloader which - given an array of java byte codes from "somewhere" - can create an internal representation of a Class which can then be used with `new` etc.

In this scenario interfaces are just special classes.  Methods and fields are available when the class has been loaded.

Comment: That's a good point. If you want to understand this, how classloaders work is a fundamental concept.

Comment: The OP links (heh) to a part of the JVM spec that explicitly mentions linking as part of the activities the JVM performs after loading a class

Comment: of course Java as a "linker".  Even if the JLS hadn't specifically named the process "linking" (see JLS 5.4 *Linking*) there would still the "concept" (to reuse a word you like) of a linker.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, no need to be snide. Feel free to write a better answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking the JVM does not link. Except if you want to name JIT compiling linking.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt  The wording in the question resembles the C linker which (at least used to be) a completely separate step creating new files on disk.   The JVM does not do this as a separate step but in memory on the fly.

Comment: Years later we now have jlink https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm Does this question now have a different answer?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Not really.  The question is about combination of stuff into a jvm-executable format.  That is not the job of jlink.

Answer (score 15):

First of all: methods are always part of a class. Interfaces are basically just special classes, and packages are just a part of the fully qualified name of a class with some impact on visibility and the physical organization of class files.

So the question comes down to: how does a JVM link class files? The JVM spec you linked to says:

> The Java programming language allows
>   an implementation flexibility as to
>   when linking activities (and, because
>   of recursion, loading) take place,
>   provided that the semantics of the
>   language are respected, that a class
>   or interface is completely verified
>   and prepared before it is initialized,
>   and that errors detected during
>   linkage are thrown at a point in the
>   program where some action is taken by
>   the program that might require linkage
>   to the class or interface involved in
>   the error.
>
> For example, an implementation may
>   choose to resolve each symbolic
>   reference in a class or interface
>   individually, only when it is used
>   (lazy or late resolution), or to
>   resolve them all at once, for example,
>   while the class is being verified
>   (static resolution). This means that
>   the resolution process may continue,
>   in some implementations, after a class
>   or interface has been initialized.

Thus, the question can only be answered for a specific JVM implementation.

Furthermore, it should never make a difference in the behaviour of Java programs, except possibly for the exact point where linking errors result in runtime `Error` instances being thrown.

Answer (score 10):

Java doesn't do linking the way C does. The principle unit is the class definition. A lot of the matching of a class reference to its definition happens at runtime. So you could compile a class against one version of a library, but provide another version at runtime. If the relevant signatures match, everything will be ok. There's some in-lining of constants at compile time, but that's about it.

Answer (score 5):

As noted previously Java compiler doesn't have a linker. However, JVM has a linking phase, which performed after class loading. JVM spec defines it at best:

> Linking a class or interface involves verifying and preparing that
>   class or interface, its direct superclass, its direct superinterfaces,
>   and its element type (if it is an array type), if necessary.
>   Resolution of symbolic references in the class or interface is an
>   optional part of linking.
>
> This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when
>   linking activities (and, because of recursion, loading) take place,
>   provided that all of the following properties are maintained:
>
> - > A class or interface is completely loaded before it is linked.
> - > A class or interface is completely verified and prepared before it is
>   >     initialized.
> - > Errors detected during linkage are thrown at a point in the program
>   >     where some action is taken by the program that might, directly or
>   >     indirectly, require linkage to the class or interface involved in the
>   >     error.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4

Answer (score 2):

Linking is one of the three activities performed by ClassLoaders. It includes verification, preparation, and (optionally) resolution.

**Verification** : It ensures the correctness of .class file i.e. it check whether this file is properly formatted and generated by valid compiler or not. If verification fails, we get run-time exception java.lang.VerifyError.

**Preparation** : JVM allocates memory for class variables and initializing the memory to default values.

**Resolution** : It is the process of replacing symbolic references from the type with direct references. It is done by searching into method area to locate the referenced entity.