# How and when does a class resolve any reference to another class?

Tags: java, plugins, classloader

I have some questions about how checking for a reference to a class is handled by the JVM. I find the documentation is slightly unclear on how the following scenario would work under the hood.

Imagine I have these two classes:

```
class AlphaClass {

    public AlphaClass {
    }

    public int someProcess() {
        return int result = BetaClass.someStaticProcess();
    }
}
```

and

```
class BetaClass {

    public BetaClass {
    }

    public static int someStaticProcess() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

They are both loaded by custom ClassLoaders. So, my AlphaClass is loaded by ClassLoaderA, and BetaClass is loaded by ClassLoaderB. The parent of both of these loaders is the AppClassLoader.

Now that I have both of these classes loaded into the JVM, I choose to instantiate an object of type AlphaClass. After I have instantiated the AlphaClass object, I choose to call the method someProcess(). It works, and it returns 1. At some point after this I then unload BetaClass, by destroying ClassLoaderB, and for the sake of argument we will assume that it gets garbage collected right away.

After a period of time I then create a new class loader, ClassLoaderC, whose parent is the AppClassLoader. This ClassLoaderC will load the BetaClass class. After this is done, is it possible for the same AlphaClass object that I instantiated earlier to run its someProcess() method?

If this would not work, why not? And what ways around this would be possible?

EDIT: In order to sum up my example and question, now that you have read some background on what I am trying to accomplish. Does the reference to the static method in BetaClass become broken by unloading and reloading BetaClass, or will it still work after the loading/unloading?

Comment: How should `BetaClass` #1 be gc'ed while there are still live references to it (e.g. from an instance of `AlphaClass`)? - Answer: It cannot be gc'ed, hence the original `AlphaClass` instance will hold on to the "old" `BetaClass` until collected itself.

Comment: @Hanno - Would a reference to call a static method inside a method that at that point isn't being called keep the ClassLoaderB from being GC? I assumed this would not be picked up on as a strong enough reference to keep it.

Comment: @Brso - Sorry if it's not clear, I will try and reword it..

Comment: @brso - In practice I'm writing a plugin loader, where there are seperate classloaders for different 'groups' of plugins. Several plugins may make use of plugins in seperate groups, so there is some possible dependency between them. I have to allow functionality where a particular group of plugins can be unloaded, updated, and then reloaded, without taking down the main applicaiton. I want to know if this would end up breaking other plugins that make use of these newly updated plugins. And if I might hav to reload them too. I thought abstracting the question might make it simpler to answer.

Comment: @Seb When exactly classes are loaded seems to be unspecified (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440426/1015327). They just have to be there when they are used for the first time. So whether or not referenced classes are loaded eagerly or lazily is probably implementation dependant.

Comment: @HannoBinder - Ok, so this link between the referenced class and the instantiated object that uses it. Is it specific to that particular loaded class? Or can you unload the class, then reload it, and that link that exists between the instantiated class and the static class would still point to the newly loaded class? As if the instantiated class had no idea the other one was unloaded and reloaded?

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure that A can actually "see" B when B is not loaded by a parent classloader of A's?

Comment: If `AlphaClass` is loaded by `ClassloaderA` and `BetaClass` by `ClassloaderB`, `BetaClass` will be loaded again by `ClassloaderA` when/if necessary. Therefore `AlphaClass` will never see the `BetaClass` that was loaded by `ClassloaderB`.

Comment: @Kayaman - How would ClassLoaderA know where to look for BetaClass?

Comment: @Seb Depends on the classloader's type. An `URLClassLoader` would have a set of `URL`s to search, but it would first delegate to its parent classloader to see if it knows of the class. If neither the parent classloader or the `URLClassLoader` can find the class, a `NoClassDefFoundError` would be thrown.