# how to read jmod file(JAVA's jmod file) in c

Tags: java, c

I'm trying to read jmod file as zip using `libzip` but got an error message :"Not a zip archive".

I tried to read jmod file in c using libzip the code as below:

```
zip_open("/xxxxx/java.base.jmod",0, &errno);
```

but without success.

Nevertheless, the jmod file can be unzipped by "unzip" command.

So what's the jmod file type?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right format? What does `file` say?

Comment: What error message do you get, in addition to "Not a zip archive"? Any error codes? Are you sure that the arguments to `zip_open` are correct?

Comment: `unzip` can unpack it because the real zip header is at the end of the file. The "PK" header seems to be four bytes in, if you skip/delete the first four bytes, it should start looking more like a zip.

Comment: Other than that it's the uhh [JMOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732915/why-did-java-9-introduce-the-jmod-file-format) format.

Comment: thanks all. double checked : 1. there is no other error code.   2. arguments to zip_open are correct.

Comment: succeed!!!   1. buffered the jmod file using char* and skip the first 4 bytes.  2. use zip_open_from_source instead of zip_open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jmod files are designed to be a file format controlled by team OpenJDK and not user-readable. The fact that `unzip` can read them **is an implementation detail**. If you write code that relies on this, you should assume that with some future OpenJDK release your C code will just break.

### Option 1 - go with the flow

Thus, instead, use the `jmod` tool. Call that executable directly. This does of course require that you either ask the user that they install a JDK and tell you where it lives so you know where to find that executable, or that you ship a JDK build with your software, or that you build it yourself and ship it along. java is open source but if you do it that way I'm pretty sure you'd have to GPL your project.

### Option 2 - hack around it - the zip file format

#### Background

The zip file format is actually a container format. It's really closer to 'tar' than 'gz' - it describes how to store directory structures (zip files know the file names of the packed-up stuff, after all!), and properties such as comments, whether an entry is encrypted or not, and which compression algorithm is used. Every entry can be compressed differently!

In that sense, a billion and a half things can feasibly be termed a zip file. This is problematic, because writing a zip tool that can unzip everything imaginable is difficult. Hence, there's the ISO/IEC 21320-1 standard that is **a subset**. For example, it restricts the 'compression algorithm used' to either 0 (no compression at all) or 8 (deflate algorithm). No other algorithm is allowed, in the sense that another number is a perfectly valid zip file, but ISO/IEC 21320-1 compatible tools **cannot read such a zip file**.

**Lesson 1: Things that `unzip` can unzip do not have to be valid zip files in the sense of ISO/IEC 21320-1 - zip can do a lot more. But most zip libraries and other zip-capable tools CANNOT read anything that isn't ISO/IEC 21320-1 compatible**.

Zip files have an interesting trick: The actual header data, as in, the dir structure, which compression algorithm was used, and so on, are **at the end of the file**. Most file formats store such things at the start!

The reason zip works that way, is that this 'trick' allows the `zip` tool's `-u` (update) feature to work: You can add some entries to a zip file and this **does not** require rewriting the whole file. Most file systems don't mind if you overwrite bytes in a file, nor do they mind if you append bytes at the end, but if you start inserting bytes in the middle, you can't do that - you'd have to rewrite the entire thing.

If you have a gigantic 4GB zip file and you want to append a tiny little text file, it's quite painful if this tiny addition means the headers are different, *if the headers are at the front*, because then the whole 4GB needs to be rewritten. zip doesn't work that way - the headers are at the end, so to add another file, you can leave 3.99GB untouched, write the compressed added file after that, and then only rewrite the 'headers' (the dir structure and such).

Almost nobody uses this 'update' feature and few libraries let you do it, so this may be irrelevant to you. Nevertheless, it explains **why** the zip file format is one of those weirdos where, to know if a file is a zip and to start unpacking it, **you must start at the end and look backwards**.

However, because various tools just cannot operate on that weirdness and REQUIRE that a file start with something that uniquely identifies the file, _the `zip` tool writes `PK` (the byte sequence in ASCII) first, *then* compressed file data, *then* the headers. This way tools can see the PK and know it's a zip file.

**Lesson 2: The unzip tool does not require this PK and in fact completely ignores it, it ONLY looks at the end of a file and takes it from there. However, other zip-capable tools may require the PK start. unzip does not**.

Yes, you can prepend any random crap to the front of a zip file and it will not affect what `unzip` does in any way.

### jmod

Jmod uses the above 2 facts to its advantage. Because the jmod spec explicitly does not want to spec that all jmods are valid zips, i.e. it wants to keep the door open to change the file format at a later date, jmods **do not start with PK**. The zip file format doesn't require this, after all (at least, the `unzip` tool doesn't. ISO/IEC compatible zips do require it. jmods aren't ISO/IEC compatible zip files. But they are unzip compatible). Instead, jmods start with the jmod header.

The JMOD header is the letters 'JM' (ascii 0x4A ascii 0x4D), then 2 more bytes indicating the major and minor version of the jmod file format (currently that's always 0x01 and then 0x00, for major version 1, minor version 0), and then the actual jmod content follows.

For JMOD format v1.0, 'the jmod file format' is just: "A zip file, structures like -this-", where '-this-' is quite a long story about e.g. having a root-level dir named 'classes', and so on.

**Because the `unzip` tool only looks at the end and doesn't care what garbage you prepend to the front of a zip file, the unzip tool doesn't care one iota about that 0x4A 0x4D 0x01 0x00 in the front)**.

But, evidently, `libzip` *does care*.

### The fix

Figure out if you can tell libzip to ignore the first 4 bytes or otherwise provide it a stream that has lopped off the first 4 bytes. Alternatively, tell libzip to ignore trying to scan for 'validity' and just do what `unzip` does and look at the end of the file. Alternatively, find another C-based zip tool that works like that. Alternatively, copy the file over, starting from the 4th byte.

More generally you should really open up the JMOD and read the first 4 bytes. If the first 4 bytes aren't the exact sequence 0x4A 0x4D 0x01 0x00 **you should abort with an error** because if it's not exactly that, you have no idea what the rest of the bytes represent. They might be a rar file now instead, who knows. The OpenJDK team makes no promises - if that header isn't exactly that, the format can be *completely different*. If you don't like that, your only option is to call `jmod` or compile the latest release of jmod into your deployed executables.

Comment: thanks for your answer. let me have a try.

Comment: succeed!!!   1. buffered the jmod file using char* and skip the first 4 bytes.  2. use zip_open_from_source instead of zip_open.